# How to highlight current dates using css?

Tags: html

i cant seem to find the solution to highlight current date in my codes. below are the css codes for my calendar.php

```
/* Highlight the "current" day */
.dates li .active {
padding: 5px;
background: #1abc9c;
color: white !important
}
```

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. Update your question and add `css` tag. 2. Include the HTML snippet as well, so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: the code is almost similar to this one https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-web-calendar-in-php except that i want to add in the highlight of current date

Answer (score 0):

You don’t give a lot of information but in case the active class is on your li element the css selector should be:

```
.dates li.active
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
/* Highlight the "current" day */
.dates li .active {
padding: 5px;
background: #1abc9c;
color: white !important;
border:1px solid;
}
```